# Memoizing both useState and mobx observable dependent state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, memoization

I have store with currencies. It stores array of currency info objects. It is initialised on load of page and might be updated during user activities. The store has method `currencies.getCurrencyInfoByTicker(ticker)`

It returns info object from array of currencies.

If `ticker` is mobx observable, it works OK. I can wrap it with computed like this

```
const info = computed(() => {
    currencies.getCurrencyInfoByTicker(ticker);
}.get();
```

But if `ticker` is state from useState, I don't understand how to memoize it properly. I can't use useMemo, because in this case I have to add `store.currencies` as a dependency. And it breaks the encapsulation.

```
const info = useMemo(() => store.getCurrencyInfoByTicker(ticker), [ticker, store.currencies]);
```

And I can't use computed, because it will not account ticker value, because it is not observable.

The only solution I see now is to make ticker observable. It works, but I don't like to create setter for ticker value manually. I really like how it works in react useState:

```
const [ticker, setTicker] = useState<string | null>(null);
```

vs

```
const [ticker] = useState(() =>
    observable({
        ticker: null,
        setTicker(value) {
            this.ticker = value;
        }
    })
)
```

And it is also not very convenient to add types to this code.

Comment: Maybe you could just use this in your store for example? https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#computedfn